# Automatically recognize whether data is a tabular text format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tabular

I have messages that are text with the following format:

```
  Name         Number1      Number2     Number3(ID)
somename1    1234.5678      273.4234      2783
somename2                   2384.2       12.54
somename3     234.1                     98234.2
```

As can be seen, there are some numbers that may be missing from the columns due to the nature of the data. However, the `Name` column will always have something since it is the unique identifier.

I am getting this data as a `str`, and would like to figure out two things:
a) Given other strings as well in the data, figure out how to recognize this tabulated format data (i.e., an indicator saying is_tabular = 1, or not). The other `str` data would be some other, non-tabular datapoints.

b) How to automatically save this text (which is in `str` format) and tabulate it despite missing data points in the table, i.e. save it as a Pandas DataFrame or NumPy array or another type of useful format. The problem is that the number of spaces between the missing datapoints and each column of the `str` is not always consistent.

I have thought of various ways to try to save this tabular format, as well as recognize if the given `str` is a tabular format str or not. I have considered predictive approaches, rule-based appraoaches (using regex), as well as even OCR-type approaches to converting this tabular-format string to a Pandas DataFrame or otherwise.

However, it seems my approach has not been successful, and I'd like if there is an algorithm or approach to follow in order to recognize this string as a table (return a boolean saying whether the string is a tabular format or not), as well as if there is an easy way to convert this to an appropriate data format such as Pandas DataFrame, NumPy array, etc. despite the missing values. Since the data is not comma-separated (this is just a string in a certain format, with `\n` characters in between each line), I would like to know if the columns are separated by whitespace (spaces and tabs) as shown above, but the width of whitespaces may not be consistent on each line, is there a way to convert this text into a DataFrame in an easy manner?

Answer (score 0):

A heuristic approach like this seems to work. It reads the first row to figure out the starting offset of each header, then uses that information for each row to find out the most likely column for each datum.

<del>The `col_offset` parameter is an unfortunate fudge factor required when the column headers are not left-aligned c.f. the start of the data.  This could be replaced by looking through not only the columns, but the rows proper too, to see how much to adjust the inferred column start offset to accommodate for this.</del>

EDIT: I implemented the heuristic discussed above. Works nicely.

```py
import re

# at least 3 consecutive non-whitespace is data; adjust if necessary
data_re = re.compile(r"[\S]{3,}")


def examine_headers(header_row, data_rows):
    column_headers = []
    for i, match in enumerate(data_re.finditer(header_row)):
        start = match.start(0)
        if i == 0:
            # First column always starts at position 0.
            start = 0
        else:
            # Look "down" at the rows to find a character column
            # that is only whitespace.
            while start:
                for row in data_rows:
                    if not row[start].isspace():
                        # Ah, this character column contains a space,
                        # so move to the left and try again.
                        start -= 1
                        break
                else:
                    # For/else: we didn't break off the loop!
                    # Found the column where there's only space left -
                    # adjust back right by one, we're done
                    start += 1
                    break
                    # Check for overlaps, just in case.
            assert start > column_headers[-1][1], "column sanity check fail"
        column_headers.append((match.group(0), start))
    return column_headers


def extract_row(column_headers, row, col_offset=0):
    row_data = {}
    for data_match in data_re.finditer(row):
        try:
            matching_header = [
                header
                for header in column_headers
                if header[1] <= (data_match.start(0) + col_offset)
            ][-1]
        except IndexError:
            print(f"No matching header for datum {data_match} on row {row}")
        else:
            row_data[matching_header[0]] = data_match.group(0)
    return row_data


# ------


rows = """
  Name         Number1      Number2     Number3(ID)
somename1    1234.5678      273.4234      2783
somename2                   2384.2       12.54
somename3     234.1                     98234.2
"""

rows = rows.strip("\n").splitlines()


column_headers = examine_headers(rows[0], rows[1:])

for row in rows[1:]:
    print(extract_row(column_headers, row))
```

The output is

```
{'Name': 'somename1', 'Number1': '1234.5678', 'Number2': '273.4234', 'Number3(ID)': '2783'}
{'Name': 'somename2', 'Number2': '2384.2', 'Number3(ID)': '12.54'}
{'Name': 'somename3', 'Number1': '234.1', 'Number3(ID)': '98234.2'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heuristic approach, it's very helpful!. However, would there also be a way to automatically recognize whether a text is in this type of "table" format vs. other strings which are not? I am trying to categorize a dataset of strings that are either A) in tabular format or B) a one line string (or other unstructured text). I have been thinking of different approaches, including 1) rule-based, 2) machine learning, 3) other ideas (hence optical character recognition - OCR). However, I think there should already be existing solutions to recognize tabular string data out there

Comment: Well, other text probably won't have so many runs of consecutive whitespace, so if you're scanning through text line-by-line, you could use that as an indicator.